# NSPredicate doesn't filter table view properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nspredicate

I'm developing reminder app and I'm facing some issues, one of them is when user tap on one of the category the table shall be reloaded based on the chosen category; the task name and category are reloaded correctly with no issues, but the time and date are not filtered as shown in photos below

I believe there's something wrong in code below, how I can solve this issue?

**ReminderTable.swift**

```
 class ReminderTable: UITableViewController,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{   

        @IBOutlet weak var menuViewRelative: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var categroyFilter:UISegmentedControl!
        var reminders:[ReminderData] = []
        var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!
        let reminderFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Reminder")
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            title = "Reminder"
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)




            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Reminder")
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"time", ascending: true)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]


            if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

                fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
                fetchResultController.delegate = self

                do {
                    try fetchResultController.performFetch()
                    reminders = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects as! [ReminderData]
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }



            }


                  loadData("All")


             tableView.allowsSelection = false
             self.navigationController!.toolbarHidden = false


        }

        override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
            categroyFilter.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        }




        func loadData(category:String){

            if category == "All"{


                do{
                    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Reminder")
                    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key:"time", ascending: true)
                    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
                    reminders = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [ReminderData]

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }catch{
                    fatalError("error")
                }

            }else{


            do{

                let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Reminder")
                  request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category = %@", category)
                reminders = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [ReminderData]
                 self.tableView.reloadData()

            }catch{
                fatalError("error")
            }
            }

          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }



        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
            self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = false


        }


        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


            return reminders.count
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let task = fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                as! ReminderData

            let cellIdentifier = "cell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReminderListCell

            cell.name.text = reminders[indexPath.row].name
            cell.category.text = reminders[indexPath.row].category
            cell.date.text = task.stringForDate()
            cell.time.text = task.stringForTime()


            return cell
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            if editingStyle == .Delete {
                // Delete the row from the data source
                reminders.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            }

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

            let RemoveAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Remove",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in


                if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {


                    let remove  = UIAlertController(title: "Are You Sure You Want Delete this Reminder ?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    let Yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action) in

                        let reminderToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ReminderData
                        managedObjectContext.deleteObject(reminderToDelete)

                        do {
                            try managedObjectContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }


                    }
                    remove.addAction(Yes)


                    let No = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
                    }
                    remove.addAction(No)



                    self.presentViewController(remove, animated: true) {}


                }
            })

            let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

                    tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editReminder", sender: cell)

            })

            RemoveAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 247/255, green: 93/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1)
            editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 21/255, green: 137/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
            return [RemoveAction,editAction]
        }

        @IBAction func unwindToHomeScreen(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        }


        func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
        }


        func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
            // 1
            switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            case .Update:
                tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            default: break
            }
        }

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "editReminder" {

               // let task = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

                let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
                let task = navController.topViewController as! Reminder

                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! ReminderListCell) {
                    task.reminders = reminders[indexPath.row]
                }


            }
        }


        func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

            switch type {
            case .Insert:
                if let _newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
            case .Delete:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
                }
            case .Update:
                if let _indexPath = indexPath {
                    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }

            default:
                tableView.reloadData()
            }

            reminders = controller.fetchedObjects as! [ReminderData]
        }

        func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }


        @IBAction func selectCategory(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

            let selectedValue = sender.titleForSegmentAtIndex(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)


            switch selectedValue!{

            case "Task":
               loadData(selectedValue!)
                break
            case "Medication":
                loadData(selectedValue!)
                break
            case "Appointment":
                loadData(selectedValue!)
                break
            default:
                loadData(selectedValue!)
                break

            }
        }


        override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

            var fixedFrame:CGRect = self.menuViewRelative.frame
            fixedFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y
            self.menuViewRelative.frame = fixedFrame
        }

    }
```

**ReminderData.swift**

```
class ReminderData : NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var category: String?
    @NSManaged var time : NSDate?

    func stringForDate() -> String {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        if let date = date {
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        } else {
            return ""
        }


    }

    func stringForTime() -> String {

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        if let time = time {
            return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(time)
        } else {
            return ""
        }


    }


}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Please show the content of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you fill in the actual content - I am guessing something is wrong there. To make the problem clear: You expect the time to be 5:35 (the same as in the first screenshot)?

Comment: exactly, but instead it keep showing 05:34 PM, how ever when I open reminder it shows me the correct data, for example when I open **test 2** it shows me 5:35 PM which means the problem is not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I guess the problem in `NSPredicate`

Comment: Side-notes: You're reloading the table view always twice, `break` statements are not needed in Swift and you could reduce the switch expression to an one-liner since nothing is really switched.

Comment: @vadian I'll take your advice into account, thanks

Comment: Where is the date formatted and the cell values set? Dollars to doughnuts it's on a code path executed only when the cell is initially created, but not when it's reused. But show us and we'll tell you for sure.

Comment: @alexcurylo I've updated my code above

Comment: In your predicate "category = %@"  should be double "==" like so: category == %@

Comment: You're making a general mistake. Since you're using a `NSFetchedResultsController` you don't need to use a parallel data source array (that causes your issue). When you switch the category just change the predicate and refetch the data. Create the `NSFetchedResultsController` as lazy initialized property like suggested in the Apple template. And the managed object context is supposed to be a non-optional.

Comment: PS: And forget those horrible tutorials which propose optional bindings paranoia in the `didChangeObject` delegate method. All passed index paths are 100% safe to be non-nil in the particular type switch.

Comment: @vadian " parallel data source array" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Actually you don't need the property `reminders` at all nor the `executeFetchRequest` statements. The fetched results controller can manage everything in a very convenient way.

Comment: what?! how I suppose to fetch data without this help pf this property?

sorry, it might my questions seems weirds, since I've been learning iOS developments only since few months

Comment: That's what `NSFetchedResultsController` is for. The (arranged) objects in the controller represent the data source array. Pass a different fetch request and call `performFetch()` to rearrange the objects. Create a new master / detail project in Xcode with checked Core Data checkbox and you get almost the entire code for free.

Comment: you were right !, how ever my main problem hasn't been solved yet, in fact it got even worse now when I filter table view the only first reminder is shown

Comment: Sorry, there is more than one issue in the code.

Comment: Check for name and category task.name and task.category are working fine in cellForRow by replacing reminders[.... lines

Comment: instead I replaced `task.stringForDate()` and `task.stringForTime()` with `reminders[indexPath.row].stringForDate()` and `reminders[indexPath.row].stringForTime()` and my problem has been solved.

thanks to you @ArunGupta, you gave me the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
task.stringForDate()
task.stringForTime()
```

with

```
reminders[indexPath.row].stringForDate()
reminders[indexPath.row].stringForTime()
```